# Texmaker error "could not start the command. pdflatex -syntex=1"

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I know there are lots of answers about this topic but unfortunately, none of the solutions worked for me. Thus, please before marking my question as a duplicate, read what I have tried so far.

I can not even compile a simplest tex file as below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Mood}
Test test test
\end{document}
```

and get an error as the title says. Here is what I tried so far:

- On the command line, I simply called pdflatex and it worked. So, there should not be a path issue.
- Even though the path seems ok, I tried to provide the full path of pdflatex to Texmaker.
- I first installed Miktex and then Texmaker. Both of them are the latest versions.
- Refreshed FNDB.

None of these suggestions from other questions worked for me.

Comment: It should be `-synctex=1` You missed `c`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by correcting a typo in compilation options